# Making multiple tables based off another table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, filter

I have a number of columns that are in the format 'NameX(TypeY)'. The format is like so:

```
total =  pd.DataFrame(table):

         NameA(Type1)    NameA(Type2)    NameA(Type3)   NameB(Type1)   NameB(Type2)    NameB.(Type3)
set1           1               1              1             2              3               4
set2           2               3              1             1              0               2
set3           2               2              1             0              0               3
```

So my goal right now is to get a table for each Name (A, B, X...) in this sort of format and I do not want to change the set row so an example output for Name A would be:

```
     Type1       Type2       Type3
set1    1           1           1
set2    2           3           1 
set3    2           2           1
```

I was thinking about using a for-loop somehow, but couldn't quite figure out how to get multiple tables like that.

Any help would be really appreciated! I am quite new to programming and python and so still working on some of the more basic priciples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

For one:

```
df2 = df.filter(like='NameA', axis=1).rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('NameA', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', ''))
```

For List:

```
Dflist = ['NameA','NameB' ] 
DfDict = {}

for e in Dflist: 
    out = df.filter(like=e, axis=1).rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(e, '').replace('(', '').replace(')', ''))
#     print out , "\n"
    DfDict[e] = out

DfDict["NameA"]

#      Type1  Type2  Type3
# set1      1      1      1
# set2      2      3      1
# set3      2      2      1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dfs = defaultdict(pd.DataFrame)

for name_sample, series in df.iteritems():
    name, sample = name_sample.split('.')
    dfs[name][sample] = series
```

The above gives you a dict with one table per unique "Name":

```
        {'NameA':      Sample#1  Sample#2  Sample#3
         id                               
         id1         1         1         1
         id2         2         3         1
         id3         2         2         1,
         'NameB':      Sample#1  Sample#2  Sample#3
         id                               
         id1         2         3         4
         id2         1         0         2
         id3         0         0         3}
```

This relies on the fact that you can add columns to a `DataFrame` after construction, and it uses `defaultdict` to get similar behavior for the outer container.

Performance should be good regardless of the number of rows, but if you have a huge number of columns there may be a better way (because the above relies on a Python loop over the columns)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still having a little trouble with this approach! Whenever I try the name_sample.split('.') line, I am getting a Value Error saying that there are "not enough values to unpack". Any ideas?

Comment: @CallieJester: That's because I wrote my answer to your original question.  Since that time you changed your column naming convention from `NameA.Sample#1` to `NameA(Type1)`.  I'm sure you can figure out from the link in my answer about string processing how to get the names out of your new column name formats.  I will not be updating my answer, because it's not fair that you change the data format of your question after it's already answered once.